# Automate Suspended orchestrations to be resumed automatically

Tags: web-services, biztalk, biztalk2006r2

We have a BizTalk application which sends XML files to external applications by using a web-service.

BizTalk calls the web-services method by passing XML file and destination application URL as parameters.

If the external applications are not able to receive the XML, or if there is no response received from the web-service back to BizTalk the message gets suspended in BizTalk.

Presently for this situation we manually go to BizTalk admin and resume each suspended message.

Our clients want this process to be automated all, they want an dashboard which shows list of message details and a button, on its click all the suspended messages have to be resumed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this within an orchestration and catching the connection error, just add a delay shape configured to 5 hours. Or set a retry interval to 300 minutes and multiple retries on the send port if that makes sense. You can do this using the rule engine as well.

Answer (score 1):

Why not implement an asynchronous pattern?

You make it so, so that the orchestration sends the file out via a send shape while initializing a certain correlation set.

You then put a [listen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee253551(v=bts.10).aspx) shape with at one end:
 - the receive (following the initialized correlation set)
 - a delay shape set to 5 hours.

When you receive the message, your orchestration can handle it gracefully.
When you don't, the delay shape will kick in and you handle accordingly.

Benefit to this solution in comparison to the solution of 40Alpha will be that your orchestration will only 'wake up' from a dehydrated state if the timeout kicks in OR when the response is received. In the example of 40Alpha, the orchestration would wake up a lot of times, consuming extra resources.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look a product like [BizTalk 360](http://www.biztalk360.com/).  It has those sort of monitoring and command built into it. I'm not sure it works with BizTalk 2006R2 though, but you should be thinking about moving off that platform anyway as it is going out of Microsoft support.